# C++ Auto typecast

Tags: c++, casting

I was surprised that the compiler automatically casted an Integer to my own defined Class

```
CCoolClass(long numerator = 0, long denominator = 1);
```

I did overload the operator + like this

```
friend CFraction operator + (CCoolClass left, CCoolClass right);
```

Why does this work and not lead to a compiler error ? Where does the auto-typecast from integer to CCoolClass come from?

```
CCoolClass a = CCoolClass(2,3) + 3;
```

I do understand this is cool, but I was rather surprised.
Regards

Comment: The compiler did **not** cast anything. The compiler **converted** the value. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Answer (score 5):

It's because you didn't tell the compiler that your constructor can only be used explicitly. That means it can do implicit type conversions to your class.

To make your constructor explicit, so it can't be used in type conversions like these, you declare it `explicit`:

```
explicit CCoolClass(long numerator = 0, long denominator = 1);
```

Comment: So the compiler is just assuming it's valid to cast an integer to to CCoolClass(integer)? Well it worked in this specific case, but otherwise I should remember explicit ?

Comment: @user3002004: It's not assuming anything. You've defined a non-explicit conversion constructor, so the conversion is valid.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a typecast, it's an implicit constructor. Your constructor uses default parameters, so your code becomes:

```
CCoolClass a = CCoolClass(2,3) + CCoolClass(3);
```

...which is equivalent to

```
CCoolClass a = CCoolClass(2,3) + CCoolClass(3,1);
```

You would have gotten a compilation error if you made your constructor explicit like Joachim's answer (because implicit construction will be disallowed), or if you did not specify any default parameters (because `CCoolClass(3)` will be invalid).